# What is the accepted way to handle unsigned data in java

Tags: java, unsigned

I read (and am currently using this) that I can use a long whenever I need an unsigned int.  This is working fine for me, but feels like a poor design.  Is there a better, more accepted, way to do it?  What about unsigned longs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only unsigned primitive type in Java is `char`, which has a very specific meaning to denote a unicode character, using `long` is the most idiomatic way to go.

By default, JAXB maps `xsd:unsignedInt` to `long`, too. ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding#Default_data_type_bindings))

**Edit**: If you know the top bit to be 0, or only use operations where the sign doesn't matter (for instance, you're just passing data through), `int` is probably more common. JAXB only defaults to `long` because it can't know how you intend to use the data.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have unsigned types by choice, you are using the signed types that are larger than the original unsigned type to work around the limitation but so you are using twice of the needed memory.

**In java there is no concept of unsigned .**